# OPC UA Client Install-Package OPCFoundation.NetStandard.Opc.Ua

Tags: c#, opc

I have a Quastion about the Client with the Install Pack OPCFoundation.NetStandard.OPC.UA. I browse beforehand so that I know the node ID at all. Now I don't know how to get the live data

How can I see the live Data with this Client?
Have somebody good examples for me?

With my Code Browse the Client the Server.

```
using Opc.Ua.Client;
using Opc.Ua.Configuration;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;

namespace Browse
{
   class Browse
   {
       public List<ExpandedNodeId> listeVorwarnungen = new List<ExpandedNodeId>();
       public List<ExpandedNodeId> listeMaschinenID = new List<ExpandedNodeId>();
       public void PLC(ApplicationConfiguration config, EndpointDescription selectedEndpoint)
       {
           using (var session = Session.Create(config, new ConfiguredEndpoint(null, selectedEndpoint, EndpointConfiguration.Create(config)), false, "", 60000, null, null).GetAwaiter().GetResult())
           {
               ReferenceDescriptionCollection refs;
               Byte[] cp;
               session.Browse(null, null, ObjectIds.ObjectsFolder, 0u, BrowseDirection.Forward, ReferenceTypeIds.HierarchicalReferences, true, (uint)NodeClass.Variable | (uint)NodeClass.Object | (uint)NodeClass.Method, out cp, out refs);
               Console.WriteLine("DisplayName: BrowseName, NodeClass");
               foreach (var rd in refs)
               {
                   if (rd.DisplayName == "PLCs")
                   {
                       Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}, {2}", rd.DisplayName, rd.BrowseName, rd.NodeClass);
                       ReferenceDescriptionCollection nextRefs;
                       byte[] nextCp;
                       //Browse Ordner PLCs
                       session.Browse(null, null, ExpandedNodeId.ToNodeId(rd.NodeId, session.NamespaceUris), 0u, BrowseDirection.Forward, ReferenceTypeIds.HierarchicalReferences, true, (uint)NodeClass.Variable | (uint)NodeClass.Object | (uint)NodeClass.Method, out nextCp, out nextRefs);
                       foreach (var nextRd in nextRefs)
                       {
                           Console.WriteLine("- {0}: {1}, {2}", nextRd.DisplayName, nextRd.BrowseName, nextRd.NodeClass);               
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       }

       public void Station(ApplicationConfiguration config, EndpointDescription selectedEndpoint,string Station)
       {
           using (var session = Session.Create(config, new ConfiguredEndpoint(null, selectedEndpoint, EndpointConfiguration.Create(config)), false, "", 60000, null, null).GetAwaiter().GetResult())
           {
               ReferenceDescriptionCollection refs;
               Byte[] cp;
               session.Browse(null, null, ObjectIds.ObjectsFolder, 0u, BrowseDirection.Forward, ReferenceTypeIds.HierarchicalReferences, true, (uint)NodeClass.Variable | (uint)NodeClass.Object | (uint)NodeClass.Method, out cp, out refs);
               //Console.WriteLine("DisplayName: BrowseName, NodeClass");
               foreach (var rd in refs)
               {
                   if (rd.DisplayName == "PLCs")
                   {
                       //Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}, {2}", rd.DisplayName, rd.BrowseName, rd.NodeClass);
                       ReferenceDescriptionCollection nextRefs;
                       byte[] nextCp;
                       //Browse Ordner PLCs
                       session.Browse(null, null, ExpandedNodeId.ToNodeId(rd.NodeId, session.NamespaceUris), 0u, BrowseDirection.Forward, ReferenceTypeIds.HierarchicalReferences, true, (uint)NodeClass.Variable | (uint)NodeClass.Object | (uint)NodeClass.Method, out nextCp, out nextRefs);
                       foreach (var nextRd in nextRefs)
                       {
                           if (nextRd.DisplayName == Station)
                           {
                               Console.WriteLine("-+ {0}: {1}, {2}", nextRd.DisplayName, nextRd.BrowseName, nextRd.NodeClass);

                               ReferenceDescriptionCollection nextnextRefs;
                               byte[] nextnextCp;
                               //Browse Ordner PLCs
                               session.Browse(null, null, ExpandedNodeId.ToNodeId(nextRd.NodeId, session.NamespaceUris), 0u, BrowseDirection.Forward, ReferenceTypeIds.HierarchicalReferences, true, (uint)NodeClass.Variable | (uint)NodeClass.Object | (uint)NodeClass.Method, out nextnextCp, out nextnextRefs);
                               foreach (var nextnextRd in nextnextRefs)
                               {
                                   if (nextnextRd.DisplayName == "Programs")
                                   {
                                       Console.WriteLine("+ {0}: {1}, {2}", nextnextRd.DisplayName, nextnextRd.BrowseName, nextnextRd.NodeClass);
                                       ReferenceDescriptionCollection nextnextnextRefs;
                                       byte[] nextnextnextCp;
                                       //Browse Ordner PLCs
                                       session.Browse(null, null, ExpandedNodeId.ToNodeId(nextnextRd.NodeId, session.NamespaceUris), 0u, BrowseDirection.Forward, ReferenceTypeIds.HierarchicalReferences, true, (uint)NodeClass.Variable | (uint)NodeClass.Object | (uint)NodeClass.Method, out nextnextnextCp, out nextnextnextRefs);
                                       foreach (var nextnextnextRd in nextnextnextRefs)
                                       {
                                           if (nextnextnextRd.DisplayName == "DB_MaschinenID")
                                           {
                                               Console.WriteLine("+ + {0}: {1}, {2}", nextnextnextRd.DisplayName, nextnextnextRd.BrowseName, nextnextnextRd.NodeClass);
                                               ReferenceDescriptionCollection nextnextnextnextRefs;
                                               byte[] nextnextnextnextCp;
                                               //Browse Ordner DB_MaschinenID
                                               session.Browse(null, null, ExpandedNodeId.ToNodeId(nextnextnextRd.NodeId, session.NamespaceUris), 0u, BrowseDirection.Forward, ReferenceTypeIds.HierarchicalReferences, true, (uint)NodeClass.Variable | (uint)NodeClass.Object | (uint)NodeClass.Method, out nextnextnextnextCp, out nextnextnextnextRefs);
                                               foreach (var nextnextnextnextRd in nextnextnextnextRefs)
                                               {
                                                   //Console.WriteLine("+ + + {0}: {1}, {2}", nextnextnextnextRd.DisplayName, nextnextnextnextRd.BrowseName, nextnextnextnextRd.NodeClass);
                                                   ReferenceDescriptionCollection nextnextnextnextnextRefs;
                                                   byte[] nextnextnextnextnextCp;
                                                   //Browse Ordner MaschinenID
                                                   session.Browse(null, null, ExpandedNodeId.ToNodeId(nextnextnextnextRd.NodeId, session.NamespaceUris), 0u, BrowseDirection.Forward, ReferenceTypeIds.HierarchicalReferences, true, (uint)NodeClass.Variable | (uint)NodeClass.Object | (uint)NodeClass.Method, out nextnextnextnextnextCp, out nextnextnextnextnextRefs);
                                                   foreach (var nextnextnextnextnextRd in nextnextnextnextnextRefs)
                                                   {
                                                       //Console.WriteLine("+ + + + {0}: {1}, {2},{3}", nextnextnextnextnextRd.DisplayName, nextnextnextnextnextRd.BrowseName, nextnextnextnextnextRd.NodeClass, nextnextnextnextnextRd.NodeId);
                                                       listeMaschinenID.Add(nextnextnextnextnextRd.NodeId);
                                                   }
                                               }
                                           }
                                           if (nextnextnextRd.DisplayName == "DB_Vorwarnungen")
                                           {
                                               Console.WriteLine("+ + {0}: {1}, {2}", nextnextnextRd.DisplayName, nextnextnextRd.BrowseName, nextnextnextRd.NodeClass);
                                               ReferenceDescriptionCollection nextnextnextnextRefs;
                                               byte[] nextnextnextnextCp;
                                               //Browse Ordner DB_Vorwarnungen
                                               session.Browse(null, null, ExpandedNodeId.ToNodeId(nextnextnextRd.NodeId, session.NamespaceUris), 0u, BrowseDirection.Forward, ReferenceTypeIds.HierarchicalReferences, true, (uint)NodeClass.Variable | (uint)NodeClass.Object | (uint)NodeClass.Method, out nextnextnextnextCp, out nextnextnextnextRefs);
                                               foreach (var nextnextnextnextRd in nextnextnextnextRefs)
                                               {
                                                   //Console.WriteLine("+ + + {0}: {1}, {2}", nextnextnextnextRd.DisplayName, nextnextnextnextRd.BrowseName, nextnextnextnextRd.NodeClass);
                                                   ReferenceDescriptionCollection nextnextnextnextnextRefs;
                                                   byte[] nextnextnextnextnextCp;
                                                   //Browse Ordner Vorwarnungen
                                                   session.Browse(null, null, ExpandedNodeId.ToNodeId(nextnextnextnextRd.NodeId, session.NamespaceUris), 0u, BrowseDirection.Forward, ReferenceTypeIds.HierarchicalReferences, true, (uint)NodeClass.Variable | (uint)NodeClass.Object | (uint)NodeClass.Method, out nextnextnextnextnextCp, out nextnextnextnextnextRefs);
                                                   foreach (var nextnextnextnextnextRd in nextnextnextnextnextRefs)
                                                   {
                                                       //Console.WriteLine("test {0}: {1}, {2},{3}", nextnextnextnextnextRd.DisplayName, nextnextnextnextnextRd.BrowseName, nextnextnextnextnextRd.NodeClass, nextnextnextnextnextRd.NodeId);
                                                       listeVorwarnungen.Add(nextnextnextnextnextRd.NodeId);                                                        
                                                   }
                                                   
                                               }
                                           }
                                       }

                                   }

                               }
                           }

                       }

                   }
               }
           }
       }


   }
}

namespace Abnahmetool
{
   class Program
   {
       
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           ExpandedNodeId[] aVorwarnungen = new ExpandedNodeId[1000];
           //List<ExpandedNodeId> listeVorwarnungen = new List<ExpandedNodeId>();

           Console.WriteLine("Step 1 - Create application configuration and certificate.");
           var config = new ApplicationConfiguration()
           {
               ApplicationName = "Abnahmetool",
               ApplicationUri = Utils.Format(@"urn:{0}:Abnahmetool", System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()),
               ApplicationType = ApplicationType.Client,
               SecurityConfiguration = new SecurityConfiguration
               {
                   ApplicationCertificate = new CertificateIdentifier { StoreType = @"Directory", StorePath = @"%CommonApplicationData%\OPC Foundation\CertificateStores\MachineDefault", SubjectName = "Abnahmetool" },
                   TrustedIssuerCertificates = new CertificateTrustList { StoreType = @"Directory", StorePath = @"%CommonApplicationData%\OPC Foundation\CertificateStores\UA Certificate Authorities" },
                   TrustedPeerCertificates = new CertificateTrustList { StoreType = @"Directory", StorePath = @"%CommonApplicationData%\OPC Foundation\CertificateStores\UA Applications" },
                   RejectedCertificateStore = new CertificateTrustList { StoreType = @"Directory", StorePath = @"%CommonApplicationData%\OPC Foundation\CertificateStores\RejectedCertificates" },
                   AutoAcceptUntrustedCertificates = true
               },
               TransportConfigurations = new TransportConfigurationCollection(),
               TransportQuotas = new TransportQuotas { OperationTimeout = 15000 },
               ClientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration { DefaultSessionTimeout = 60000 },
               TraceConfiguration = new TraceConfiguration()
           };
           //config.Validate(ApplicationType.Client).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
           //if (config.SecurityConfiguration.AutoAcceptUntrustedCertificates)
           //{
           //    config.CertificateValidator.CertificateValidation += (s, e) => { e.Accept = (e.Error.StatusCode == StatusCodes.BadCertificateUntrusted); };
           //}

           //var application = new ApplicationInstance
           //{
           //    ApplicationName = "Abnahmetool",
           //    ApplicationType = ApplicationType.Client,
           //    ApplicationConfiguration = config,
           //};
           //application.CheckApplicationInstanceCertificate(false, 2048).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

           var selectedEndpoint = CoreClientUtils.SelectEndpoint("opc.tcp://" + "172.22.80.145" + ":4840", useSecurity: false);

           Console.WriteLine($"Step 2 - Create a session with your server: {selectedEndpoint.EndpointUrl} ");
           Browse.Browse fkt = new Browse.Browse();
           fkt.PLC(config, selectedEndpoint);
           fkt.Station(config, selectedEndpoint, "NCU710_3_BDE_MAG"); //als letztes muss dann die station hin die überprüft werden soll
           Console.WriteLine("NodeID: {0}",fkt.listeVorwarnungen[0]);
           Console.WriteLine("NodeID: {0}", fkt.listeMaschinenID[4]);
           
       }
   }
}´´´
```

Comment: Have you looked at this : https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard/tree/1.4.370.12/Applications/ReferenceClient